# Submitting iOS app to app store - internationalisation

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm about to submit an app to app store. The app is in my native language (Persian) and it aims only at the persian speakers. I didn't go through using the process of internatiolization and stuff because it wouldn't make sense. However, when I entered iTunes Connect, I had to choose a language for it and Persian wasn't among the languages you could choose, so I chose English. The list of languages at iTunes Connect was quite small and did not cover more than 20 languages. Anyway, is that going to be problematic for my app?

I haven't submitted my app officially, I'm just going through the final steps and I'm anxious that it might cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to select Primary Language while creating New App in iTunes connect, probably you can the

> Have you checked '?' - Question mark it contains one FAQ.

From [Resources & Help](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Localization#64875326) section

**Why am I not seeing my localization language listed as a selection for Primary Language?**

If the localization has not been approved, you must submit a version with this localization to be approved by App Review before you can select it as your primary language.

If the screenshots for that localization are being derived from another localization’s screenshots, you must first manually add screenshots for the language you wish to be your primary. If the Ready for Sale version of your app is using screenshots from another language, you will need to submit an update to your app before you can select the new language.

Comment: does it mean that I should submit my app as it is and wait? do I need to go through localisation processes?